# JQuery - search elements values with given regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Lets say I have some elements like this

```
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="Andi">Andi<div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="John">John<div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="Anderson">Anderson<div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="John Smith">John Smith<div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="George">George<div>
```

I am trying to make a search functionality with regex, that will show elements based on their data-user-name text match. For example, I want when the user types `nd` in jQuery to catch both the `Andi` and the `Anderson` html elements,

when they type 'John' to catch both the `John` and `John Smith` elements,

and when they type 'John Smith' to show only the `John Smith` element.

So far I've come up with this

```
$('#inputSearchFriends').on('input', function () {
    const searchText = this.value.trim();
    $('.friendListItem').filter(function() {
        const re = new RegExp(searchText);
        return this.attributes['data-user-name'].value.match(re);
    }).show();
}
```

but it only returns the elements when the text is exactly entered.
I also need the regex pattern to be case-insensitive, so if I type 'john' it will still match 'John'.
How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/217867).

Comment: thats not what I am looking for

Comment: Your code works, for ignore case use `new RegExp(searchText, "gi")` and @LonnieBest linked answer will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple `indexOf()` as it is faster than the regex approach, lowercasing everything for the comparison. 
Demo might look a bit strange as it hides everything first, but you get the idea:

```js
$('#inputSearchFriends').on('input', function () {
    const searchText = this.value.trim();
    $('.friendListItem').hide();
    $('.friendListItem').filter(function() {
        return this.attributes['data-user-name'].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="Andi">Andi</div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="John">John</div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="Anderson">Anderson</div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="John Smith">John Smith</div>
<div class="friendListItem" data-user-name="George">George</div>
<input id="inputSearchFriends">
```

Comment: you don't use the 'new RegEx' statement which I have, is it faster without declaring a variable with 'new'?

Comment: Yes, and indexOf() is definitely faster than regex @SartherisStormhammer

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
const re = new RegExp(searchText);
```

To:

```
const re = new RegExp(searchText,'gi');
```